# How do I track the context a type resides in?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-structures, operators, implicit-conversion

I have a type that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ContextType Context;
    public int Value;
}
```

The Context is used to keep track of which context the type resides in. The problem is when an assignment is performed:

```
MyClass myClassA = ..
MyClass myClassB = ..

myClassA = myClassB;
```

The myClassA reference and its context is changed when I only want the value to be copied and the context to remain the same.

I've tried using an implicit operator but it does not allow the conversion to be to or from a base type.

I want to avoid forcing the user to use some kind of custom assignment method but if I really have to I want to prevent regular assignment to be possible (to avoid what will be a common mistake). I'd like my API to be as user-friendly as possible.

Is there a way to accomplish this behavior? Any suggestions on other ways to track context of a type?

Comment: Maybe i'm a bit confused about your description but why don't you implements a custom assignment operator which does not assign the context member variable ?

Comment: C# does not support assignment operator overloading.